# Eye Tracking on the cheap

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, eye-tracking

Looking to give eye tracking a shot, to learn the order in which the content is viewed on a desktop page or a phone, as the user goes through a click-through prototype.
Unless there's a better way, I'd either look for a recording of where the user is focusing or a heatmap of the whole session that I can overlay on a screen recording session.

So far I've looked at Tobii & Gazepoint, but they're either too expensive for my budget or not really available here in Europe, or both.

Because I'm doing this for a side project, I'm not worried about accuracy, so I'd use any of the non specialised devices I have access to: Samsung S9 & iPhone XR that have face unlock, and a MacBook Pro Retina 2015.

If all else fails, I'd consider buying a device under 100 EUR, if I could adapt it to desktop or mobile use.

I'd also like to hear about other setups you've used for eye tracking with a very modest budget.

Comment: Honestly, you can find basically endless of them by just googling. First three results:
https://imotions.com/blog/webcam-eye-tracking-vs-an-eye-tracker/
https://hackaday.com/2018/05/05/low-cost-eye-tracking-with-webcams-and-open-source-software/
https://eyezag.de/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't related UX

Comment: User Research/User Tracking/Usability Testing & User Experience go hand in hand. This should not be closed because of that reason. The only reason this should be closed is the lack of information and vagueness of the question. (product recommendation) @ShreyasTripathy

Comment: @marvinpoo - Agreed. I meant to say that it isn't directly asking a UX question but didn't elaborate on it. I wish I could change the comment

Comment: Really interested in how this can come across as vague, I gave a budget, context, reasoning + what I am to achieve (which is a heatmap for a prototype I want to analyze), gave the products I considered already and whey they didn't make the cut. How would you better reframe or add to the context, so this is less vague?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a "glasses" kind of eye tracker from https://pupil-labs.com, they re based in Berlin so it's not a problem to get hold of it in Europe. They offer two versions, a commercial one that is about 1500€ and a do it yourself one that is about 500€ but requires you to solder and assemble the parts yourself, which is not too hard. https://docs.pupil-labs.com/#diy

This one has the advantage over most of the other "cheap" eye tracker of allowing you to do research on a variety of mediums, you are not tight to a screen, it can be used for physical objects such as packaging and books as well as having the user freely move around in a space (especially with the commercial version as you can use that one connected to an Android smartphone).